# Can Prism and ASP.NET Web Parts work together?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, web-parts, prism, modularity

We are trying to pick a modular programming solution at my work.  The choice right now is Prism or ASP.NET Web Parts.

One Boss person asked if you could wrap a Prism Module in an ASP.NET Web Part so they can be used anywhere (kind of a "can I have my cake and eat it too" kind of question.)

While I don't think this is a feasible solution, I don't really know.

Anyone out there that knows some about both Web Parts and Prism that could hazard an explanation as to if this could or could not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Prism version only supports WPF & Silverlight. It does not provide any default support for the ASP.Net programming model.

If you (or your boss) are looking for guidance for decoupled applications with ASP.Net, you can probably check ASP.Net MVC which shares many of the Prism core concepts (presentation patterns, containers, areas/regions). Specifically, p&p developed a guidance about developing Web Apps which you can find [here](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20Client%20Guidance&referringTitle=Home) and download [from here](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/46436).

I hope this helps.